# Why real numbers doesn't end with infinitely many 9s?

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

In the text [TAOCP](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/112247.The_Art_of_Computer_Programming_Volume_1)

> A real number is a quantity x that has a decimal expansion
>   $$x = n + 0.d_1d_2d_3...$$
>   where n is an integer, each $d_i$ is a digit between 0 and 9, and the sequence of digits doesn't end with infinitely many 9s

Why is such a case ? Isn't all the numbers between 0 and 1 are all real ? Then the numbers which ends with infinitely many 9s should be real too, Isn't it ?

Comment: Note that $0.9999\ldots = 1$, so those numbers are already counted using digit sequences ending in infinitely many $0$s

Comment: The problem is that terminating decimals, like $1$, can also be written as $.999\dots$.  So if you allow your representation to end with infinitely many $9's$ then the representation isn't always unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are real. But note that $1=0.999999\ldots$, that $1.23=1.22999999\ldots$ and so on. What happens is that every real number has one and only one decimal expansion *except* those numbers which can be written as $\frac a{10^n}$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$. These ones have *two* decimal expansions (as in my two examples above). A natural option then consists in not to consider the decimal expansions which end with infinitely many $9$'s.